# XPathSelectElements always returns Expression must evaluate to a node-set

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xpath

I am new to using LINQ and am trying to select a node from an XML document that i've transformed.

here is the raw code:

```
// create a LINQ xml doc
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xTransformedDoc.OuterXml);

// get sibling elements to the shredding element 
IEnumerable<XElement> xe = xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElements("//" + settings.ShredNode + "[1]/(following-sibling|preceding-sibling)[name() != '" + settings.ShredNode + "']");
```

Note: earlier in the code settings.ShredNode is set to "DocRouteDetail"

at first i thought it was a problem with the complexity of the xpath statement i am using however i've tried every combination i can think of and even rolled it back to absolute basics in the VS debugger:

```
xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElements(".")
xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElements("//DocRouteDetail")
etc
```

in all cases it returns back null and it generates an exception returning "Expression must evaluate to a node-set."

this is happening in .NET framework 4.0 in c#.

i have checked and the xdoc.Root variable is not null and my xml looks like the following (full document slimmed down for security reasons):

```
<DocFWImport xmlns:dtfn2="urn:my-scripts2">
  <Header SendDateTime="2014-04-03T19:26:50" />
  <Request>
    <DocRouteDetail MessagePurpose="1002" ResourceKey="A" >
      <DocStop StopNumber="0" Type="0" LocationType="DEPOT">
      </DocStop>
      <DocStop StopNumber="1" Type="3" LocationType="CUSTOMER" >
      </DocStop>
      <DocStop StopNumber="2" Type="0" LocationType="DEPOT">
      </DocStop>
    </DocRouteDetail>
    <parmRouteTemplateKey>TEAM</parmRouteTemplateKey>
    <DocRouteDetail MessagePurpose="1002" ResourceKey="B" >
      <DocStop StopNumber="0" Type="0" LocationType="DEPOT">
      </DocStop>
      <DocStop StopNumber="1" Type="3" LocationType="CUSTOMER" >
      </DocStop>
      <DocStop StopNumber="2" Type="0" LocationType="DEPOT">
      </DocStop>
    </DocRouteDetail>
    <parmRouteTemplateKey>SINGLE</parmRouteTemplateKey>
    etc
  </Request>
</DocFWImport>
```

it should have returned the 2 parmRouteTemplateKey elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the `XPathSelectElements`'s fault, your XPath query is invalid - namely the part with the `|` operator. The other basic queries you're mentioning **do** work. If they really don't, then there's some another error outside the code you've posted.

I'd write it as

```
//DocRouteDetail[1]/parent::*/child::*[name()!='DocRouteDetail']
```

that way it selects what you need.

Comment: Hey pjotr, thanks, this did indeed select them. after reading your post i did notice that my preceding-following statements were invalid... i forgot the ::node(), your example did solve the problem. not sure why i was trying to use the following/preceding when i could just go back to the child again.

Comment: I am having a new issue with this solution, the selectelements works however when i then try and create a list of distinct element names using the following code:
List<string> elToConsider = xe
.GroupBy(el => el.Name.ToString())
.Select(grp => grp.First().Name.ToString())
.ToList<string>();
i'm getting an xpath exception:
The XPath expression evaluated to unexpected type System.Xml.Linq.XText.

Comment: This criteria did not actually work, after rewritting my select distinct i discovered it is actually returning the "TEAM" as a selected element rather than the node (parmRouteTemplateKey). I also changed it from * to node() xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElement("//" + settings.ShredNode + "[1]/parent::node()//child::node()[name() != '" + settings.ShredNode + "' and not(text())]");

Comment: A co-worker spotted the problem, i had an extra slash between the parent/child, re-marking this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @pjotr, your XPath attempt is not valid. You can try to combine 2 XPaths using union operator (`|`) like this instead :

```
var xpath1 = "//" + settings.ShredNode 
                  + "[1]/following-sibling[name() != '" + settings.ShredNode + "']";
var xpath2 = "//" + settings.ShredNode 
                  + "[1]/preceding-sibling[name() != '" + settings.ShredNode + "']";
IEnumerable<XElement> xe = 
        xdoc.Root
            .XPathSelectElements(xpath1 + " | " + xpath2);
```